# How can I use unique hostnames across VMs with a shared root filesystem? Is this method even recommended?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, hostname

## Background

I am creating several VirtualBox instances to use as Web development environments (Arch host/Debian guests), and I want them to share most files but have an additional drive for each machine, mounted at `/mnt`. This is more memory-efficient than simply cloning the entire disk, and allows me to install tools across systems without the need to reinstall on other projects that use the same programs, files, etc. I am aware of the limitation that two machines won't be able to work at the same time, but I don't switch contexts very often so it's a non-issue for me.

On each machine, for example, the `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` files are replaced with symlinks pointing to respective files on the individual drive, mounted at `/mnt` with some other useful directories that are specific to each project. This allows me to swap out drives for different projects while using the same, basic filesystem.

```
localhost ~ > ls -la /mnt/etc/host*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16 Dec 10 08:04 /mnt/etc/hostname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 128 Jan  6 07:20 /mnt/etc/hosts
localhost ~ > ls -la /etc/host*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9 Aug  7  2006 /etc/host.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Jan  5 22:36 /etc/hostname -> /mnt/etc/hostname
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  14 Jan  5 22:34 /etc/hosts -> /mnt/etc/hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 411 Dec  9 21:25 /etc/hosts.allow
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 711 Dec  9 21:25 /etc/hosts.deny
```

## Issue and Code

However, I see that my shell prompt doesn't respect the values in `hostname` or `hosts`, instead defaulting to `localhost`. These files need to contain different hostname values for each VM, or I'll easily lose track of which machine I'm working in. Here are the files:

*/mnt/etc/hosts*

```
# Static table lookup for hostnames.
# See hosts(5) for details.

127.0.1.1 mc-development.localdomain mc-development
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

*/mnt/etc/hostname*

```
mc-development
```

### Edit 1

Here's the output of `hostnamectl`:

```
localhost ~ > hostnamectl
   Static hostname: mc-development
Transient hostname: localhost
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: …
           Boot ID: …
    Virtualization: oracle
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
            Kernel: Linux 4.19.0-13-amd64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

I thought that maybe the way I was symlinking to a different drive was the cause of the hostname definition issue, but according to this output, it is reading the files just fine. So it would appear that Fish is honoring the *transient* hostname when I want it to display the *static* hostname.

Any ideas of how to do this? What are the key differences between the two hostname types?

By the way, this shows up in Bash, too.

```
localhost ~ > bash
matt@localhost:~$
```

## What I've Tried

I thought that maybe the order in which the drives were being mounted might make a difference because if the OS reads a link to a file that hasn't been loaded yet, it could cause an issue like this. However, changing the order of `fstab` entries did not help.

### Edit 2

As mentioned in a comment on Ljm Dullaart's answer, copying the `/usr` directory didn't seem to work. My Debian box complains at boot that it is missing programs from `/bin` and `/sbin`, including `/bin/init`.

Here are the steps I took:

#### 1. Boot to a live image and mount the drives, shared inside guest.

```
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/mnt
```

#### 2. Move the entire `usr` directory to the shared drive.

```
# mv /mnt/usr /mnt/mnt
```

#### 3. Create the symlink.

```
# ln -s /mnt/mnt/usr /mnt/usr
```

#### 4. Boot, and…

[image: error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not recommended.

In general, you would have a number of filesystems that can be shared (some even read-only), but the root filesystem is not one of them. The system boot process uses this filesystem.

In your case, I would share `/usr` an possibly `/opt`.   You would keep separate per machine on the rootfs (sizes are on my machine; just to give you an impression of the memory use):

```
15M     bin
94M     boot
34M     etc
778M    lib
28M     lib64
```

You will probably keep separate per machine

```
4.9G    var
```

That is because logs are kept here. You should not want to mix the logging of your instances that way.

You will still be sharing

```
22G     usr
4.7G    opt
426G    home
```

As per *EDIT 2*_

This linking that you do will not work. You let `/usr` on `/dev/sda1` point to `/mnt/mnt/usr`. Not to `/usr` on sdb1, but to `/mnt/mnt/usr`.

However, you did something more; `/sbin` must still be on the rootfs. The fact that it isn't there is just wrong.

What you will need to do is to re-install both machines (sorry), with exactly the same installation media and the same options.

Machine 1:

When the partition-editor appears, select a partition as follows:

- `/dev/sda1` : root filesystem (`/`)
- `/dev/sdb1` : `/usr`
- `/dev/sdb2` : `/home`
- `/dev/sdb3` : `/opt`

Then, install the lot.

When machine 1 is up and running, shut it down.

Next, for machine 2: exactly the same. Make sure that sda is it's own disk and that sdb is the shared disk.

Note that upgrade and updates will be a PITA, but as this is a virtual environment, you may choose to re-install from time to time.

____ Yet another edit _____

Because debian uses `systemd`, the described method is no longer possible. See  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/UsrMove for an explanation why. (Fedora, but applies to all systemd-distro's)

Comment: Could I share `/home` as well?

Comment: Yes. I added this to the answer.

Comment: Hmm, copying the `/usr` directory didn't seem to work. My Debian box complains at boo that it is missing programs from `/bin` and `/sbin`, including `/bin/init`. That's a bit strange considering that I haven't touched those directories, but it makes some sense because there is quite a bit of symlinking going on already. Have you tried this before? What were your steps? I will update my question shortly to include my process.

Comment: Yes i've done this; this is what is done when `/usr` is on NFS for example. Did you `cp -L`?

Comment: `cp -rL /mnt/usr /mnt/mnt` just tells me "No such file or directory" multiple times.

Comment: I would suggest that you already have a number of dead links. `cp -L` will try to resolve the links and copy the real file instead of just the link. If it complains `No such file or directory`, that normally means the link may exist, but the target file of the link is gone.

Comment: Okay, well my shared drive (containing `/home` and `/opt`) got corrupted somewhere in the process, so now I need to start the installation from the beginning. This is a blessing in disguise; now that I have a better idea of how my file system is to be structured, I can start over knowing what I should be doing. Perhaps I should've taken a snapshot before stretching data across drives, also, but hey, hindsight's 20/20.

Comment: On the new install, when I run `cp -rL` I still get `No such file or directory` and `run-init: can't execute 'sbin/init': no such file or directory`.

Comment: Does my edit answer that question?

Comment: `/sbin` is just a link to `/usr/sbin`. That's not something I did; it's the default configuration. Perhaps this is different in other distros?
I was hoping to keep `/home`, `/usr`, and `/opt` in one partition, though. That is, unless there's a way to define these partitions dynamically (like through LVM, with which I am unfamiliar). Remember, my main goal is storage efficiency, so I don't want multiple statically defined partitions if I can avoid it. I suppose I could create three shared drives, `sdb`-`sdd`, but I would rather keep everything on one virtual drive if possible.

Comment: And yes, your edit, among all else, has been very helpful. I've marked this as accepted because although I haven't exactly reached a solution yet, you've pointed me in the right direction, and I can seek help with LVM in another thread or somewhere else.

Comment: Hm. Seems it is indeed distro dependent. I'm on Slackware, and there it works exactly as expected. Seems that systemd-distributions decided to "clean-up" sbin and for those distributions, /usr can't be on a separate filesystem anymore.Of course, it is never systemd's fault.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118211/discussion-between-matt-mccarthy-and-ljm-dullaart).