# How can I share system folders across filesystems using LVM or by other means?

Tags: lvm, nfs

## Background

First off, this is a continuation of *[How can I use unique hostnames across VMs with a shared root filesystem? Is this method even recommended?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627847/how-can-i-use-unique-hostnames-across-vms-with-a-shared-root-filesystem-is-this)* I started a new thread because the edits and comments were veering off topic, and this isn't the type of forum where I should be asking multiple questions on the same thread. Besides, my basic question of *Is this recommended?* had already been answered: no.

Before, I was attempting to share an entire root filesystem across virtual machines and picking a few directories to have different contents on each machine (e.g. `/var`). I learned, however, that only a few directories in `/` should be shared (in my case, `/home`, `/usr`, and `/opt`), but despite learning quite a bit from the accepted answer, I'm still unsure of how to actually implement this.

## My Setup

Currently I have one VirtualBox VM running, which is a basic Debian install with all system directories (e.g. `/home`, `/var`, `/tmp`) on one partition on the first drive. Future machines will start with clones of this first drive. The second drive is used as a PV as part of VG `shared`.

- *Host machine:* Arch (5.10.4-arch2-1)
- *Guest machine:* Debian 10

  - *Primary drive*: 50GB dynamically allocated VDI, appears as `/dev/sda`

    - *Partition 1*

      - Takes all available space
      - Appears as `/dev/sda1`
      - Ext4 filesystem
  - *Shared drive*: 16GB dynamically allocated VDI, appears as `/dev/sdb`

    - *Partition 1*

      - Takes all available space
      - Appears as `/dev/sdb1`
      - Contains a VG (named `shared`) with three (roughly) equal LVs

        - Each LV takes ~1/3 of the space
        - Appear as `/dev/shared/usr`, `/dev/shared/home`, and `/dev/shared/opt`
        - Ext4 filesystems

Here are some LVM outputs and the contents of `/etc/fstab`:

[image: LVM/fstab]

I haven't added `home` or `opt` entries yet to fstab yet; I'm waiting to get `usr` working because that's been the most challenging.

## Next steps

From a live ISO, I continue by mounting the filesystem at `/mnt` and backing up `/mnt/usr` and copying its contents to `/mnt/dev/shared/usr`, temporarily mounted at `/mnt/mnt/shared/usr`.

```
root@archiso ~ # mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
root@archiso ~ # cd /mnt
root@archiso /mnt # mv usr usr.bak
root@archiso /mnt # mkdir usr
root@archiso /mnt # mkdir -p mnt/shared/usr
root@archiso /mnt # mount /dev/shared/usr mnt/shared/usr
root@archiso /mnt # cp -rL usr.bak/* mnt/shared/usr
root@archiso /mnt # vim etc/fstab # add last line as shown in section above
```

## The Issue

When I reboot to the Debian system, I see a timeout as `systemd` attempts to mount `/dev/shared/usr`.

[image: timeout]

If I login as root, I notice that `/usr` is mounted, but as read-only.

## Goals

My ultimate goal is to manage secondary memory efficiently by sharing the forementioned directories across machines. My immediate goal is to mount `/usr` from the LV on startup, so my multiple VMs can use it (one at a time, unlike through NFS which can serve multiple machines).

If what I'm trying to do would be better accomplished through other means (like NFS), point me in the right direction and I will try things that way, instead. It's worth noting that I'm not experienced with LVM or NFS.

Comment: If no-one mentioned this on your other question, take a look at how Sun Microsystems handled this in the '90s - they did diskless and almost-diskless workstations with highly shared filesystems really well

Comment: @roaima Is this what you mean? [Wikipedia: Diskless node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskless_node)

Comment: No. The "diskless" is less important than the "Sun Microsystems"

Comment: Could you provide a resource, then? I only have a vague understanding of what I'm searching for. You might be better capable of finding relevant search engine results.

Comment: Also, I haven't found much success on the Oracle site.

Comment: @roaima I just realized you probably didn't get notified for my last two comments, so I'm tagging you again.

Comment: @roaima Also, on that note, I think it wouldn't be practical to use the exact scheme Sun used before systemd was adopted. See [freedesktop.org: separate-usr-is-broken](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/kw56up/how_can_i_share_system_folders_across_filesystems/) as posted by a commentor on [this cross-post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/kw56up/how_can_i_share_system_folders_across_filesystems/). Any thoughts on any of that?

Comment: I've been looking at https://drbl.org/ to see if they've got up-to-date documentation on what can be shared read-only and what must be read-write and local. Unfortunately it looks like the Sun Microsystems stuff I remember of, has been subsumed into Oracle and the documentation updated and pruned heavily